# Using / Accepting Certificate in Xamarin Forms Application

Tags: xamarin.forms, httpclient, client-certificates

[image]

In my Xamarin Forms(iOS & Android) Application I am using Azure API app for consuming the API's. Previously I was using Bareer Token only for authorisation. And recently the team handling services implemented **Client Certificate** as an additional security measure. But I am not sure how I can achieve the same in Xamarin Forms.

I am using .Net HttpClient for consuming the API's.

I have found several people asking the same question in the stackoverflow and Xamarin forums. But I haven't get a solution for Xamarin Forms that can be used for both iOS and Android.

I do find people advising to implement this specific to Platform; But there also I can't find any method to use it along with my current HttpClient implementation.